# Get the row number onclick using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have wore below code and its working.But I want row number when a ROW clicked(Hope Ajax is okay) and pass it to a php code in same page. I tried javascript it worked,bt not in the way I want. If its in Ajax its better. Any HELP would b gratefull :)

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$search=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM bus_fares WHERE route_no='$_POST[route_no]'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($search);
$search1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT fare FROM fare  limit $num_rows ");
$x = 0;
echo" <table  id='my_table'><tr><th>Fare Stage</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Fare</th>
        </tr>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search) and $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search1)){
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>".$x."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row1['fare']."</td>";
echo"</tr>";
$x++;
}
echo"</table>"; 
}
```

Comment: So your actual question is?...

Comment: you'll still need PHP to retrieve the MySQL values. you can use jQuery to display them on clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is to not only store the visual data in your table but also some sort of meta data. There are several ways to achieve this.

**Method #1: (ab)use the `id` or `class` attributes:**

The resulting HTML would look like this:

```
<!-- example with the id-attribute: -->
<tr id="mysql_row_1"> ... </tr>
<tr id="mysql_row_2"> ... </tr>

<!-- example with the class-attribute: -->
<tr class="mysql_row_1"> ... </tr>
<tr class="mysql_row_2"> ... </tr>
```

This would both generate valid HTML but you would abuse attribute-tags for a purpose they're not implemented for, what is generally regarded as bad. Imagine if you had to store more than just one value. You could assign multiple classes, but you'd get stuck with the id-tag then. Therefore: don't do this!

You'd have to change your code like this to achieve this solution:
(I assume you want the value of `$x` as the rownumber.)

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search) and $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($search1)) {
    echo '<tr class="mysql_row_'.$x.'" onclick="getRowNumber()">';
    echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row1['fare']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $x++;
}
```

The javascript part:

```
function getRowNumber() {
    var rowNumber = this.className.replace("mysql_row_",""); // fetches the classname and removes the extra-strings
    alert(rowNumber);  // alerts "1", "2", ...
}
```

**Method #2: Use the `data-*` attributes:**

This solution is valid for HTML5. *Please add additional information regarding compatibility if you have some.*

Your HTML Code will look like this:

```
<tr data-mysql_row_number="1" onclick="getRowNumber()"> .... </tr>
<tr data-mysql_row_number="2" onclick="getRowNumber()"> .... </tr>
```

And the modified javascript:

```
function getRowNumber() {
    alert(this.getAttribute("data-mysql_row_number")); // alerts "1", "2", ...
}
```

This also generates perfectly valid HTML(5) code and lets you store infinite endless amounts of information since you can specify as many `data-*` attributes as you want to.

**Method #3: use invisible `<input>` fields:**

The resulting HTML code:

```
<tr onclick="getRowNumber()">
    <td>
        Normal content of this field
        <input type="hidden" name="mysql_row_number" value="1"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the JS code to fetch the values:

```
function getRowNumber() {
    var rowNumber = this.getElementsByName('mysql_row_number')[0].value;
    alert(rowNumber); // alerts "1", "2", ...
}
```

This as well produces valid HTML but is semantically not really correct in my opinion, since the data inside the `<input>` fields is some kind of loose and not directly connected to the row. Plus you can make multiple `<input>` fields with the same name.

- I would suggest method #2 ( `data-*` ), as this is the most flexible solution and uses an attribute that has been designed to store meta-data.
- Method #1 would work the most reliable across all (older) browsers since all of them support acces to the `id` or `class` attribute via JS, as long as you keep the `id` tag unique.
- Method #3 will also be quite reliable with older browsers.

Comment: thank you guys for the reply...bt im little bit lost here. If u can give me the exact code for do this function.. Just wanna get the onclick row number to a variable in side php code

Comment: np, data attribute is a nice idea, but less compatible cross browser ;)

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to upvote my answer to give me a little rep-boost :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `echo"<tr>";` do :

```
echo "<tr id='row_".$row['id']."'>";
```

then when a tr is clicked, just retrieve `$(this)[0].id` like that with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) inside a script tag (be sure [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) is included, it's a powerful JS library, google it for additional informations) :

```
<script>
$("#my_table").on("click", "tr", function(){
  alert($(this)[0].id.replace("row_", ""));
});
</script>
```